# Dojo toolbar: buttons disappear in Firefox 4.0 and IE8

Tags: dojo, cross-browser

Do someone knows this problem? We have an application with Dojo Toolkit 1.2.3, it runs fine in Firefox 3.x and IE 6. But when used in Firefox 4, some Buttons of a Toolbar aren't visible. The funny thing is, Buttons including "drop down" menus are working.

Comment: You really should upgrade to a more recent Dojo version...  It is now at 1.6.  FF4 is a major enhancement over 3.X.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, was some kind of "not closed" div inside an dijit.Toolbar.